# Laravel DataTables color cell based on value?

Tags: css, laravel, datatable, colors, cell

I am trying to color a cell using Laravel with DataTables based on the cell value, but i can't get the raw CallBack function working.

Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#pdr_table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('ajaxdata.getdata') }}",
        "columns":[
            { "data": "ID_Piece" },
            { "data": "Designation" },
            { "data": "Status" },
            { "data": "checkbox", orderable:false, searchable:false}
        ],
        'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
            if(data[2] == 'Disponible'){
                console.log(data[2]); 
                $(row).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'green');
            }
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the console of your browser and it will show you the error which you can share here. On a first look at your code, before the `rowCallback` you are missing comma `,` after the `columns` item which will make the array to blow up. Second if you want to add a background color then you should use `background-color` css attribute because the `color` attribute will change the color of the text only.

so `data[2]` should become `data.Status` when you are renaming the cells.

Comment: After adding the `,` i got my table's data but still no color, and 0  error from browser console.

Comment: if you are checking for the Status, then thats the 2 index of the cell, as it starts from 0, not from 1. So try changing that. So `data[3]` should become `data[2]`.

Comment: Yes, but still no color.

Comment: I cannot debug your code my friend because I don't have it. Try to print out if you have any status for which you are looking for. So before the if statement print out the data[2] with `console.log(data[2]);` And inspect that in your browser.

Comment: btw, the cell should also be changed to `td:eq(2)`

Comment: Updated, take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186698/discussion-between-nakov-and-sami).